# XYZ Tiles Connection

Tags: qgis, xyz-tiles

I'm struggling to work out how to use the XYZ tiles I've created in my QGIS project.  I have managed to create the XYZ tiles and I know they have been created correctly as the index.htm file renders it correctly.

What I haven't been able to work out how to add the tiles to my project.  I want it to sit on top of OSM as an additional base layer.  I have tried a file reference to a place on my local drive and also tried uploading it to my GitHub space but, again, I can't seem to link to the tiles.

I have the tiles located here and this is the connection I'm using (it's a map of the Scottish rail network): C:/Users/Andrew/Documents/ScotRail220616/{z}/{x}/{y}.png

ScotRail220616 is the top folder within which the zoom level folders sit.

What am I missing?  Am I getting the syntax wrong for the file location?

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Still hasn't resolved it for me.  Anything else that I might be missing?  I've tried turning it immediately into a webmap (as I've used some xyz tiles that don't show in the canvas but will render in a webmap) but nothing.

Comment: It is still actual over time. I have got the same problem - QGIS window just leaves me a blank space. Syntax is the same, I'm using Windows 10 Pro.
Anyone who did meet this issue before, what actions have you taken to overcome it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the url needs a a file:// protocol and an extra slash before "C:/" i.e.

```
file:///C:/Users/Andrew/Documents/ScotRail220616/{z}/{x}/{y}.png.
```

That works for me but I'm testing on Linux not Windows.