# Link to XYZ tiles from my own server (PNG/TIFF)

Tags: qgis, url, xyz-tiles

[Problem of linkage to own xyz tiles](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/434130/xyz-tiles-connection) is still actual over time. QGIS window just leaves me a blank space after any attempts to fetch the correct syntax:
file:///D:/Users/user_name/Documents/QGIS/data/dem_merged.tif/{z}/{x}/{y}

At the same time, the original file uploaded to QGIS layers set is displayed correctly. 
I'm using Windows 10 Pro. 
Anyone who did meet this issue before, what actions have you taken to overcome it?

Comment: Does the Answer in the duplicate Question apply? [XYZ Tiles Connection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/434130/xyz-tiles-connection)

Comment: Your URL is missing the file extension {z}/{x}/{y}*.png* and you appear to be pointing to the original tif instead of the folder where the tiles are actually stored *dem_merged.tif*/{z}/{x}/{y}